# If I delete whatsapp on my iPhone, will the backup stay on iCloud indefinitely?

Tags: iphone, whatsapp

I'm trying to minimise distractions. WhatsApp is a huge one. The idea is to erase whatsapp one way or another and sporadically reinstall it to check for new messages. Ideally I want to keep all my data. I thought about using Imazing for that, but the whole process is just too slow.
One alternative would be to rely on the iCloud backup of WhatsApp. But then I need to know:

-if you delete whatsapp, how long will its backup stay on iCloud?

-how long will the server keep saving my messages? (I'm not deleting my account)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iCloud will not, per se, store your credentials for WhatsApp (due to security), rather, it will store a record that you have purchased it  (yes, this includes free items [like Facebook, and WhatsApp]). This log stays indefinitely (or rather, for the life of your iCloud account).

- WhatsApp has it's own login flow, so if you delete WhatsApp from your device, then re-download it, you will need to login again to the app.
- WhatsApp will keep all unread messages for a maximum of 30 days from the date the message was sent, after which, unless you've logged in again to retrieve the messages, will be purged.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, iCloud keeps a record of everything you've downloaded. I think that it will store any data that you've got in the app also.